# regex,PHP- remove single , double quotation and backslash from a complex json string

Tags: php, jquery, json, regex

The following snippet is just a part of a larger json. This json is passed through an ajax call from client side to server side in PHP. The json structure has the value attribute **in many places**. And this json is produced from a jQuery plugin.

**Code snippet:**

{"1":
   {**"value":"abcdefg**","style":
     {
      "autoFormatter":{}
     }
   }
}

Before saving the value in database, I need to remove any single quotation ('), double quotation ("") or backslash () from the value part (i.e. abcdefg) of the value attribute.  So I am trying to run a regular expression in the full json so that any occurrence of the previously mentioned characters is removed .

For example `"value":"xyz'abc"` should be changed into `"value":"xyzabc"`

What should be the proper way ?

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) afterwards? It's difficult to tell what your concrete trouble is. Somewhat seems like you attempted to modify the whole JSON string instead of just the value.

Comment: @mario, my intention is to modify the value attribute's value only, not the whole json

Comment: Or you could use parameterised and bound queries and then you would not have any problems storing this in the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly, can you explain in details ?

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed Can you explain why you need to remove this charachters? As RiggsFolly mentioned, there is no issue storing this in the database.

Comment: Yes sure. Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @SteffenMächtel, the reason is once the value with the mentioned characters is stored  in DB, I need to fetch it later from DB and hold it in a javascript variable. Then I call a `fromJson` method of the jQuery plugin I am using. But If those characters are present , then the JS variable shows error (malformed JSON etc). ANy way to store that value in JS with the mentioned characters included in it ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, any way to solve the issue mentioned just in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be, I think,

- import the JSON into a PHP array
- walk the array, recursively
- store it back into a JSON string.

Something like:

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

// Modify $arr.
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$value, $key) {
   if ('value' === $key) {
       $value = str_replace([ '"', "'", '\\' ], '', $value);
   }
});

$str = json_encode($arr);
```

Using regular expressions to parse a JSON string can probably be [costrued](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1428679) as "thanks, but no".

## Older PHPs

```
function cleanvalues(&$value, $key) {
   // Programmers from Blefuscu usually write this as
   // if ($key == $value)
   // -- feel free.
   if ('value' === $key) {
       // Haven't tested this, and don't think it's faster, but
       // regexes can be used here:
       // $value = preg_replace('#["\'\\\\]+#', '', $value);
       $value = str_replace(array('"', "'", '\\'), '', $value);
   }
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'cleanvalues');
```

Comment: what is about the backslah ?

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten it along the way. Fixed.

Comment: can you reply to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805089/regex-php-remove-single-double-quotation-and-backslash-from-a-complex-json-st?noredirect=1#comment94459058_53805089 ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I have added a different answer, since your *real* question is, I think, also a different one.

Answer (score 0):

## The answer to a slightly different question

This is what is called a "XY problem". You are trying to solve problem Y ("Removing SQL-problematic characters from JSON") when your *actual* problem is problem X:

> I need to fetch it later from DB and hold it in a javascript variable. Then I call a fromJson method of the jQuery plugin I am using.

So what you *need* is: "**a way of storing a textual value in a SQL-neutral, JSON-neutral, Javascript-neutral representation**".

You can do this by using Base64. Use Base64 as the "common language" between your app layers - SQL, Javascript and PHP. Then decode values when they enter a boundary, and encode them when they go out again:

```
$value = "string with weird JSON that won't go into SQL";
$val2  = base64_encode($value);
...now $val2 is stored into SQL and can be retrieved with no problems
(search can be difficult but can be done, somewhat).
```

Then you retrieve the `$val2` and can store it into Javascript with no problems, only remember it's base64. Yes, it'll take somewhat more space, but nowadays is that really a problem?

```
// Value recovered from SQL through PHP
var base64val = '{$val2}';
// base64val is a safe string, but useless.
var trueval = btoa(base64val);
// trueval is a JSON string, but not yet decoded.
var fromjson = JSON.parse(trueval);
// finally fromjson holds the real value
```

Now, you have a workflow into which *anything goes* - you can put slashes, dollar signs, quotes, double quotes and, more importantly, a lot of UTF8 characters that would have wrecked my previous answer (you may want to seek some thrills reading about "malformed UTF8 attacks and where to find them").

Comment: I have a big JSOn data, that has in many places the `"value"` attribute. This attribute holds data which I am trying to modify. So should I run `base64_encode` on the whole JSOn structure ?

Comment: Yes. That will solve all your data representation problems (unless there are more layers yet to the question:-) )

Comment: `var base64val = '{$val2}';` - why do you need the curly braces ?

Comment: Quoting f rom what you said : ` var fromjson = JSON.parse(trueval);
// finally fromjson holds the real value` - I do not need to parse the JSOn. I get a JSON value from the JS plugin application, send it to server side with `JSON.stringify`, store it in DB and then fetch again in PHP and then take it in a JS variable and then call the plugin method with the JSON as the parameter and then it is supposed to work. - this is the work flow.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed because you're decoding a *string*. The resulting output of that line from PHP would be valid Javascript, e.g. `var base64val = 'eW91IHJlYWxseSBkZWNvZGVkIHRoaXM/Cg==';`. You can then run `btoa()` on the sequence, and get the JSON code even if it contains strange characters (as long as it was valid JSON when it was encoded).

Comment: `var trueval = btoa(base64val);` reverts the encoded string to what it was before .  The relevant part is `{"value":"aabc'def"` and the JS variable just breaks at the position of the apostrophe

Comment: I mistakenly said in my earlier comment that I do not need to parse the JSOn. Actually I need it and I do it

Comment: Sorry - long day, not really up to a chat. I'd suggest you integrate the question with a minimum example of what you need to achieve, and in particular, what plugin you're feeding the JSON to. Or a screenshot of the actual problem. I'm afraid "the JS variable breaks" is not something I am familiar with.

Comment: I'll do that and post here

Answer (score 0):

I created a small test to figure out the problem. First i thought u have a problem writing the json string into the database, becouse you dont use any kind of "escape_string" or bind param.

--- UPDATE ---

Just use the json string as an object in html later without the use of $.parseJSON(jsonString).

```
<?php
/*
  CREATE TABLE `table_53805089_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `json` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
 */

// Example json string from ajax call
$jsonFromAjaxRequest = '{"1":{"value":"ab\"cd\'efg","style":{"autoFormatter":{}}}}';

// Connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'stackoverflow');

// Write into database
$query = 'REPLACE INTO `table_53805089_test` 
              (`id`, `json`) 
              VALUES (1, \'' . $mysqli->escape_string($jsonFromAjaxRequest) . '\')';
$mysqli->query($query);

// Read from database
$query = 'SELECT json FROM `table_53805089_test` WHERE id = 1';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Use in html -> javscript variable
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Error:
            // jsonString = '<?php echo $row['json']; ?>';
            // $(document).ready(function () {
            //  data = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
            //  console.log(data);
            //});

            // Works:
            var jsonData = <?php echo $row['json']; ?>;
            console.log(jsonData['1']['value']);

            // Suggestion in case $row['json'] is empty
            var jsonData = <?php echo $row['json'] ?: '{}' ?>;
            console.log(jsonData['1']['value']);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: suppose the `value` attribute is like this - "value": "abc"def". then the solution does not work because the middle quotation seems to terminate the string beforehand.

Comment: how to include single quotation, double quotation and backslash in  the 2nd parameter in `addcslashes` ?

Comment: I think its not possible to send " as value with json. Its already escaped to \"?

Comment: `var jsonString = '<?php echo addcslashes($row['json'], "'"); ?>';` - I am talking about this line.it works with single quotation but not with double quotation.

Comment: I am creating a test2 to figure this 100% out :D

Comment: `$jsonFromAjaxRequest` as you said does not have the escaping (i.e. `"value":"abcd\'efg"`). The escaping is done in server side PHP. with `json_encode`.

Comment: How is the json string created on client side? With something like JSON.parse()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185328/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-steffen-machtel).

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a completely different question about jQuery draggable and droppable here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?